# How to lazy mount Material UI tab panels or to know when a tab panel is visible?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material UI tabs to select between three TabPanels. Specifically, I'm using the [Simple Tabs Example](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#simple-tabs).

The component in my second tab needs access to such fields and methods as `elem.offsetHeight` and `elem.getClientRects()` to adjust the layout. Unfortunately these display-based things are zero or empty until the component in the panel displays. All the panels mount right away, but the second panel isn't visible on mounting, so my layout adjustments don't work when I try to run them during the mount.

I think what I need is either of two things:

1. Some way to lazy-load the contents of my tab panels. (This solution would probably be best, since the second and third panels require network calls, and makes no sense to make such a call until the panel is required.)
2. Some way to know when the contents of the panel is finally displayed so that the code can trigger the layout adjustments.

Another solution would be to set a timeout to check periodically (say every 100 ms) whether `elem.getClientRects()` produces a list with any elements, but that seems rather hacky.

---

### Addendum

I'm sorry my written description wasn't clearer. Inside my `SimpleTabs` component:

```
  <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
    <About/>
  </TabPanel>
  <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
    <ByRossPage/>
  </TabPanel>
  <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
    <ByChapter/>
  </TabPanel>
```

The `<ByRossPage/>` component contains the `getPage()` method that accesses `elem.offsetHeight` and `elem.getClientRects()`. This method is called from the component's constructor.

Comment: Can you show us some of your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out how to get the contents of the TabPanel to lazy load. I modified the TabPanel functional component like this:

```
function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <Typography
      component="div"
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
    >
      <Box p={3}>{value === index && children}</Box>
    </Typography>
  );
}
```

The only changed line is this one:

```
 <Box p={3}>{value === index && children}</Box>
```

which had been this

```
<Box p={3}>{children}</Box>
```

Comment: This is not lazy loading, u still instantiating all the components at build time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by modifying the TabPanel

```
function TabPanel(props: TabPanelProps) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;
  const panel = React.useRef();
  // this will run after the component mounted.
  React.useEffect(() => { 
     console.log(panel.current.getClientRects());
  }, []);
  return (
    <div ref={panel}>
    <Typography
      component="div"
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      <Box p={3}>{children}</Box>
    </Typography>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry what I wrote wasn't clearer. I'm trying to access `getClientRects()` from the component *inside* the TabPanel, not from the TabPanel itself.

Comment: Also, all three panels are mounted right at the start, regardless of whether the given TabPanel is visible.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same situation when i wanted to check if a div is overflowing or not, i could get it to work properly by conditional rendering the TabPanel

Example:

```
{tabIndex === 1 && (
      <TabPanel value={tabIndex} index={1}>
        <Component />
      </TabPanel>
    )}
```